# Ignoring duplicate explicit instantiations of template classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

If I have a class:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{ 
 // ...
};
```

and I explicitly instantiate it:

```
template class MyClass<int>;
template class MyClass<int>; // second time
```

I get an error on some compilers (Clang for example, but not on VC++ 2010). Why would I want to do this? Well, in some cases `T` may be a `typedef` to another type.

```
template class MyClass<my_type_1>;
template class MyClass<my_type_2>;
```

With certain build options, `my_type_1` is the same as `my_type_2` and in other cases it is different. How would I make sure that the above compiles in all scenarios? Is there a way to ignore the duplicate instantiation?

Comment: Personally I keep template code in headers and let the compiler instantiate it automatically as needed. I guess in some situations that would balloon the compile time though.

Comment: @Dave sorry, late reply, but yes the reason this was done was to reduce compile times - they were getting out of hand with all our template classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find another way to explicitly instantiate the `template` in a way that you can do metaprogramming on it.

Then instead of doing one instantiation per line, do them all in a pack.  Run an n^2 algorithm on them (at compile time) to eliminate duplicates (or, honestly, you could probably skip that: depending on how you instantiate the template, it might not care).

Something like this, assuming `Instantiate< Template, types< blah, foo, bar > >` actually instantiates the list on the template passed in as the first argument:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Test {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct types {};

template<template<typename>class Template, typename Types>
struct Instantiate {};

template<template<typename>class Template, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct Instantiate<Template, types<T0, Ts...>>:
  Instantiate<Template, types<Ts...>>
{
  Template<T0>& unused();
};

template<typename U, typename Types>
struct prepend;

template<typename U, template<typename...>class pack, typename... Ts>
struct prepend< U, pack<Ts...> > {
  typedef pack<U, Ts...> types;
};
template<typename U, typename Types>
using Prepend = typename prepend<U, Types>::types;

template<typename U, typename Types, typename=void>
struct remove_type_from_types;
template<typename U, template<typename...>class pack>
struct remove_type_from_types<U, pack<>, void>
{
  typedef pack<> types;
};

template<typename U, template<typename...>class pack, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct remove_type_from_types< U, pack<T0, Ts...>,
  typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<U, T0>::value >::type
>: remove_type_from_types< U, pack<Ts...> >
{};

template<typename U, template<typename...>class pack, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct remove_type_from_types< U, pack<T0, Ts...>,
  typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<U, T0>::value >::type
>
{
  typedef Prepend< T0, typename remove_type_from_types< U, pack<Ts...> >::types > types;
};

template<typename Types>
struct remove_duplicates {
  typedef Types types;
};

template<template<typename...>class pack, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct remove_duplicates<pack<T0, Ts...>> {
private:
  typedef typename remove_type_from_types< T0, pack<Ts...> >::types filtered_tail;
  typedef typename remove_duplicates< filtered_tail >::types unique_tail;
public:
  typedef Prepend< T0, unique_tail > types;
};
template<typename Types>
using RemoveDuplicates = typename remove_duplicates<Types>::types;

static Instantiate<Test, RemoveDuplicates<types<int, double>> > unused;

int main() {

}
```

As noted, you can probably do away with the entire eliminate-duplicates bit, because of how I'm instantiating the use of the `template`.  I am also not sure if the above use of each `template` is sufficient to instantiate it (ie, that it won't be optimized away somehow, and that the symbol will be exported).

(Recursion depth is `n` in the number of types, and total work done is `n^2` in the number of types: that is shallow enough and fast enough for any reasonable number of types, I suspect.  Fancier unique type removal is difficult, due to lack of weak ordering on naked types...)

Comment: Very interesting. I also not sure whether the template use in the `Instantiate` struct enough for an explicit instantiation. I don't have access to a `C++11` compiler so I cannot test this, but will definitely save it for later study. Quite a clever approach!

Comment: @samaursa if the `template` use is not enough, do a daisy chain call.  Then call the bottom one in an exported function that is not called by anyone.  The `template`s will be instantiated in order to export that function, and later at linking the exported function will be eliminated, but the `template`s may not if used elsewhere...

Comment: I tried using C++11, and apparently doesn't work. Reference in Instantiate apparently doesn't perform an explicit instantiation. Good idea though. I'm also looking for a solution to this, using macros is very boring and not quite efficient for my use.

Comment: @brahmin As another idea, do a sum-of-`sizeof`.  sizeof basically requires instantiation.

Comment: @Yakk doesn't change anything for me. I don't think you can explicitly instantiate except from using template : class Test<int>. And it apparently needs to be done in a cpp file, out of any function. I'm afraid there's no solution to this problem..

Answer (score 3):

Don't specialize for the typedefs, instead specialize for the relevant underlying types (such as int). That way you can typedef as many/few times as you like and you still always get the specializations you want.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion but defeats the purpose of the `typedef`. If the type changes, I will get linking errors which will take me at least a few minutes to figure out. Better than what I have right now though (+1).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a preprocessor flag for you configuration and then put template inside an `#ifdef` block.

Comment: That is a lot of defines! And sometimes the types are not defined by a configuration but can change along the way. For example, recently, a certain `TextureCoord` type that another class was using was a `typedef` of a `Vec2f` but was changed to `Vec3f` (already instantiated) causing compile errors on XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Yakk saved my days. Actually I have lots of non-type template functions with parameters calculated at compile time depend on some "#define"s. I won't know in advance their values and I want to instantiate them explicitly. But when they are conflicting, the compiler stops with the error "duplicate ...". So I followed the idea of Yakk and I made a very simple version of his. I post it here for someones possibly interested.

File 1: instantiate.h

```
#ifndef INC_INSTANTIATE_H
#define INC_INSTANTIATE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned short base> void func();

template<unsigned short base>
struct test {
    test() {
        cout << "Class " << base << " instantiated.\n";
        func<base>();
    }
    void instantiate_me(){};
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct instances {};

template<typename Types>
struct Instantiate {};

template<typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct Instantiate<instances<T0, Ts...>> : Instantiate<instances<Ts...>>
{
    T0 unused;
};

#endif
```

File 2: instantiate.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "instantiate.h"

using namespace std;

static Instantiate<instances<test<1>, test<2>, test<3>, test<4>>> unused;

template<unsigned short base>
void func() {
    cout << "Function " << base << " instantiated.\n";
}

static int initialize() {
    unused.unused.instantiate_me();
    return 0;
}

static int dummy = initialize();
```

File 3: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "instantiate.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Good day commander!\n";
}
```

It works perfectly with g++ 8.0.1 ubuntu 18.04 hyper-v windows 10. Here I do not
need to care about template duplication because I explicitly use implicit instantiation, in one file there won't never be duplication. With all functions' definitions in one file, I can instantiate it in the constructor
of the class "test" in the file instantiate.h. With plural files, I use one Instantiate, one initialize and one dummy for each, with possibly plural implementations of the class "test".

Answer (score -1):

using the extern template syntax can solve the problem, example:

```
 extern template int max (int, int);
```